# Quicksort tree diagram with "middle" pivot?

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

This is in java. Suppose that your Quick-Sort algorithm uses a pivot rule that picks the element in the “middle”. That is, for an array A[0,1,...,n−1] of size n, it uses the element in A[n/2] as pivot if n is even and the element in A[(n − 1)/2] as pivot if n is odd. Illustrate how this algorithm works using a quick-sort tree on the input:

```
[7 6 5 4 3 2 1]
```

Would the first pivot be 5 or 4? I was thinking it would be 5 since (7-1)/2 = 3 and 5 is the 3rd element, or would it be the 3rd index, which is the element 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

size of your array is 7
the size is odd so `[(n-1)/2]` will be used -> `[(n-1)/2] = [(7-1)/2] = 3`
It will be 3rd index i.e. 4th element
which is in your case 4

Answer (score 0):

[7 6 5 4 3 2 1] has 7 elements, so being odd you said it calculates the pivot using: A[(n-1)/2]

So, (7-1)/2 => 6/2 => 3rd position in the array, in your case number 4

Take into account that this kind of division will always return a truncated integer.

For example, 5/2 = 2, 3/2 = 1